# nginx config file with basic authorization

Tags: nginx

I'm building a website that I'm running through a docker container. I am receiving this error

`webserver_1  | 2019/10/01 17:50:24 [emerg] 1#1: unexpected "}" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:36
webserver_1  | nginx: [emerg] unexpected "}" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:36`

All of the curly brackets are counted for and removing this one (it's the third to last brace) would leave me with an uneven number.

This is my nginx.conf. Does anyone know what's going on?

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        location /api {
            auth_basic      'closed site';
            auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/conf.d/.htpasswd
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are missing a terminating `;` on the `auth_basic_user_file` statement.

Comment: thank you so much! I needed another set of eyes. Should this work to establish basic authentication? I fixed that and have run my site and it isn't prompting for a password